# Dynamics 365 : User roles project timesheet user work flow errors

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, finance, erp

We have upgraded our ERP environment to 10.0.24, after that timesheets are not getting for approval and when I check the workflow history on timesheets for review. It's showing an error : **“Stopped (error): X++ Exception: Work item could not be created. Insufficient security permissions for user NGanipisetti. Please review the user's security permissions to ensure they are sufficient for this workflow document and then resume the workflow.at SysWorkflowWork”.**

I have deleted the user, imported from directory and assigned the required Project timesheet user and project manager roles. Once I did the process and resume the workflow, now the workflow is working and managers are able to approve the timesheets, and timesheets going for second level approval also.

Please let me know if it have anything to do with upgrade or am I missing anything, help me here to avoid this for another users.

Because we can't do it to every user each time.

Comment: See if this helps - https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/174192/work-item-could-not-be-created-insufficient-rights?pifragment-109373=2#responses

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try if you run into this in the future is going to the "Security Configuration" form, and selecting the menu option "Data > Synchronize all" and "Data > Repair". This will ensure the security metadata is properly synchronized with the database. I've had to do this in rare cases where security was acting strangely and it fixed the issue for me.

To help in troubleshooting this error in the future and to see which D365 object has insufficient permissions, Microsoft has added logging to the LCS logs. So if you search for “Workflow User Invalid Permission Error” in the LCS Logs for the environment and time range when the error occurred, it will show you the missing permission in these 2 fields: AxObjectType and AxObjectName.